# How can i stop unity from script?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I need to close unity from my scripts. As if I clicked on the stop-button in GUI.
Can i do this directly from code, or not? I know, how i can close a scene, but need to close all processes.

Comment: Maybe `EditorApplication.Exit(0);`? http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorApplication.Exit.html

Comment: This works, but... its cut the process unity. i need just STOP, as if clicked stop button :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Application.Quit(); // Quit the deployed game/App
```

Or as Chris commented, use below code to quit Unity Editor:

```
EditorApplication.Exit(0);
```

Or you wish to pause the player:

```
EditorApplication.isPaused = true;
```

Or consider using boolean property:

```
EditorApplication.isPlaying = false;
```

Or you are talking about [this](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.Break.html)? Then try:

```
Debug.Break();  //stop running at run-time,
```

See online documentation [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.Quit.html) and [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorApplication.Exit.html).

Choose whichever that matches your intents.

Comment: EditorApplication.isPlaying = false; -- EXACTLY what i need! thx u very much :3

Comment: This is an excellent answer; however, please mind that on some players, like iOS, this is simply not supported. I haven't tested if Application.Quit() works on iOS, but even if it does, app that has a "close" button won't get approved by Apple.

Comment: Application.Quit() should work in both Mac and Windows. What test did you perform?